# Setting up SDL2 with eclipse and mingw: SDL_INIT crash

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw, sdl-2

I've been trying to rerun an old c++ eclipse project that uses SDL2, but attempting to recreate my system to the point SDL2 works at all is becoming infuriating. At this point I'm trying to reinstall eclipse, mingw and sdl, trying both 32 and 64 bit versions, but no combination works. I'm thinking its a problem with the way I'm installing it all, which is why I'll be overly-explicit as to what I did, but obviously I don't know for sure. Skip the next two paragraphs if you only care about the SDL error.

I'm using a Windows 7 64 bit machine. My first instinct is to download the 64 bit version of Eclipse Neon for c++ from the download links on their main site. 
Because I'm working on windows 64, I get the w64 version of mingw at (https)sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64. Its installer has multiple version inputs, so I pick the 7.1.0, x86_64, win32, seh and 0 options.
I include a path to the new mingw64 folder in the eclipse c++ build environment, and I'm able to select the 'mingw gcc' toolchain in a new project and run a new helloworld project successfully.

I then try to add SDL2, following the steps from https://www.caveofprogramming.com/c-for-complete-beginners/setting-up-sdl-windows.html. I get the newest version, SDL 2.0.5, from the libsdl download page, choosing the development library for MinGW 32/64-bit version. I then unzip it, pick the x86_64-w64-mingw32 version and move the lib / include files (including the cmake and pkgconfig sub-folders) from that folder to the new mingw64 folder from before.

At this point I'm at step 6 in the tutorial; I continue the rest without any problems (at step 17 I add the same mingw32 / SDL2main / SDL2 linkers: is this correct?), adding the SDL2.dll from the initial SDL2\bin folder to the debug folder once the project is built. However, when I copy in his example code and step through with the debugger, an error occurs at SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); that I'm unable to step into. It doesn't output anything onto the console, [looks like this in the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCCj.png), and when I try to resume the program stops working and terminates. No error code or anything.

The most relevant solutions I've found about this always involve using 32 bit for everything, but repeating the above process with 32 bit versions of the above result in the same error at the same place. I looked at the SDL wiki and tried all possible inputs for SDL_INIT: it crashed the same way when I tried SDL_INIT_TIMER, SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK and SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER, but the other inputs didn't cause any errors. I ultimately want to use SDL_image and SDL_tff like the projects I was doing before, and I know I finagled a way to make it work that I can't reproduce.

Comment: Update: I'm able to completely work through the tutorial at http://www.willusher.io/pages/sdl2/, so sdl windows will come up and output whatever I want as they should. I can't do SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING or the other init macros mentioned, but SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_EVENTS) doesn't cause any errors and lets me do what I need to do, so far at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very much not sure if this is the actual solution, but reinstalling mingw with the custom options 7.1.0, x86_64, posix, sjlj and 0 made INIT_EVERYTHING work with no crashes and perform exactly how it should.

Answer (score -1):

You must use `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` to use [sdl-2](/questions/tagged/sdl-2).

Also, I recommend to not use `using namespace std;` as it would create problems if your code develops further. Second, I highly recommend to use a [try-catch](/questions/tagged/try-catch) block to handle exception, without them when an error occurs, you will have no idea where it came from.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

try
{
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("SDL failed to initialise! ERROR: "));
  }
}
catch (std::runtime_error const& msg)
{
    printf("%s", msg.what());
    if (SDL_GetError() != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", SDL_GetError());
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying <SDL2/SDL.h> results in 'no such file or directory', and its explained in the caveofprogramming tutorial steps 18-22 as to how that should work I think.d

Comment: I know using namespace std is bad practice, it was just the default opening helloworld project code to prove that it works at all. Removing std namespace results in the same error.

Comment: Adding the try-catch block doesn't catch the error when it happens, it still causes the exception at SDL_INIT and doesn't continue debugging